# Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on null If I set the site in another language in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

If I set the site in another language, english spanish or french, the header menu and cart doesn't work, but once i reload that page error will be hide and display page perfectly.

I am getting following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on null

My code is as below:

**classes\module\Module.php**

```
public function display($file, $template, $cache_id = null, $compile_id = null)
{
    if (($overloaded = Module::_isTemplateOverloadedStatic(basename($file, '.php'), $template)) === null) {
        return Tools::displayError('No template found for module').' '.basename($file, '.php');
    } else {
        if (Tools::getIsset('live_edit') || Tools::getIsset('live_configurator_token')) {
            $cache_id = null;
        }

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'module_dir' =>    __PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.basename($file, '.php').'/',
            'module_template_dir' => ($overloaded ? _THEME_DIR_ : __PS_BASE_URI__).'modules/'.basename($file, '.php').'/',
            'allow_push' => $this->allow_push
        ));

        if ($cache_id !== null) {
            Tools::enableCache();
        }

        $result = $this->getCurrentSubTemplate($template, $cache_id, $compile_id)->fetch();

        if ($cache_id !== null) {
            Tools::restoreCacheSettings();
        }

        $this->resetCurrentSubTemplate($template, $cache_id, $compile_id);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->smarty` is null. Find why

Comment: @Federkun thanks for giving your valuable time, when i print that i got value and also get error but when i reload page error will be remove and i see the page content